# I have created values for RSA encryption but it doesn't always work

Tags: encryption, rsa

I am using the values as follows:

$(p, q, n, \phi(n), e, d) = (1033, 5039, 5205287, 5199216, 65537, 3784241)$

Yes, I have made sure $e$ and $\phi(n)$ are coprime.

For example, if I were to encrypt the value $13130$, I would get $4664915$ and then I decrypted $4664915$ and got $13130$.

The problem is when then I encrypted the number $1310731326$ and got $3386045$, when I went to decrypt $3386045$, I got $18660$ which is nowhere near $1310731326$.

I've been trying all day and still can't find the solution. Can someone help me please!?!?!

Comment: and furthermore, please make sure to read why textbook RSA is insecure

Answer (score 4):

Your message has to be smaller than n to be correctly encrypted / decrypted with RSA.

Comment: i see now. so the larger n the larger the value for m can be